# Wordpress dynamic widget by location?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i need to show the widget based on user location , for a testing purpose i have created the by using following code

```
if( function_exists( 'register_sidebar' ) )
register_sidebar( array( 'name'=>'Madurai-Right',
'before_widget' => '<div class="widget relativ">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h2>',
'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );
```

and getting the widget like below

```
<?php $city="Madurai";  echo $side_bar= "'$city-Right'"; ?>
    <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar($side_bar) ) :?>
    &nbsp;
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Here city is the location, so based on the location i am getting the sidebar as `dynamic_sidebar($side_bar)` it doesn't working

But if i use without the variable inside the `dynamic_sidebar('Madurai-Right')` is working well, any idea? what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2):

Dude replace this `$side_bar= "'$city-Right'"` with this `$side_bar= $city."-Right"`

Comment: If this answer helped you then you can accept this as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct for hardcoded side-bar="city-Right"

```
<?php $city="Madurai";  echo "side_bar='" . $city . "-Right'"; ?>
    <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar($side_bar) ) :?>
    &nbsp;
<?php endif; ?>
```